# Can't update ACF field in WooCommerce operation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

For unknown reason my function doesn't update ACF custom field. The function is to search for special order note (I don't know why plugin developer themselves didn't add tracking number to order meta).

It seems like everything's correct, but still I see no update. What have I missed?

```
// add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_object_save', 'find_tracking', 10, 1); // Also tried, it runs function 3 times
add_action( 'save_post_shop_order', 'pax_find_tracking', 10, 1);

function find_tracking ($order_id) {
    global $wpdb;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $ID = $order->get_id();
    $status = $order->get_status();

    if ('completed' == $status) { // it's for testing

        $table_perfixed = $wpdb->prefix . 'comments';
        $sql = "SELECT `comment_content` FROM $table_perfixed WHERE `comment_post_ID` = $ID AND `comment_content` LIKE '%Shipment data sent to server%'";
        $result = $wpdb->get_var($sql); // checked, correct unique result 
        if ($result) {
            $result = mb_substr($result, 44); // checked, correct tracking number 
            update_field('my_tracking_field', $result, $ID); // Also tried without $ID
            //$order->add_order_note($result); // Checked result — it's string, not empty, $result is fine
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any difference if you use the field name -vs- the field key? (its not supposed to matter), but `update_field` is a pretty simple function, do you see your change anywhere in the post meta table at all?

Comment: Does `update_field` return true?

Comment: I tried to use the field key, it's no matter. ```update_field``` returns false. The field exists. I can add value manually.

Comment: Just double checking, callback of `pax_find_tracking` vs `find_tracking` isn't the issue? the only other suggestion is to ensure the ACF definition for your field is defined at point of update_field, maybe its not finding the field by name.

Comment: No, I just removed pax before posting :) function name in the file is correct, tested on order notes. The issue is field update

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find problem's roots, but the solution is to use `update_post_meta` instead of `update_field`.

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_tracking_field', $result );
```